# How to make evil paragraph movements work in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, evil

I'm using `evil` with this sample `org` file:

```
* test0
  test1
  test2

  test3
* test4

    |test5
* test6
```

When the cursor is on line "test6" and I press <kbd>{</kbd> (`evil-backward-paragraph`), Emacs places the cursor between lines "test2" and "test3". Then, when I press <kbd>}</kbd> (`evil-forward-paragraph`), the cursor goes to "test4".  That's not how it works in Vim.

How do I make next/prev paragraph keys place the cursor on the first empty line below/above current cursor position, like in Vim?

Comment: And what if the cursor is already at an empty line? What behavior do you expect in this case?

Comment: The same which is first empty line above or below current line :)

Comment: The functions work as you expect when in `text-mode`, but not `org-mode`.  That's probably because `org-mode` uses a different concept of what constitutes a paragraph break.  See the variable `paragraph-separate`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to the `org-mode` hook:

```
(setq paragraph-start "\\|[     ]*$")
(setq paragraph-separate "[     ]*$")
```

(Note that these character classes, the contents of `[]`, contain one space and one literal tab, which may not render correctly in your browser)

These are the paragraph boundaries definitions from text-mode.  So:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (setq paragraph-start "\\|[  ]*$"
                                 paragraph-separate "[  ]*$")))
```

Instead of a `lambda`, you could wrap it in a named function:

```
(defun my-org-hook ()
  (setq paragraph-start "\\|[    ]*$"
        paragraph-separate "[     ]*$"))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-hook)
```

Comment: I don't know how to add it to "org-mode hook" (just adding these lines to `.emacs` doesn't work), but I solved this issue by moving to Spacemacs - it works much better there.

Comment: if you're using emacs you should get familiar with hooks

Comment: @Kossak if you moved to Spacemacs, could you close your issue then?

Comment: @Kossak: if this answer resolves the problem, could you accept it so that we can close the post as answered?

Comment: I just checked and using this org-mode hook doesn't make it work like in vim (in org-mode at least, in text files it does, without the hook).

Comment: I used this approach with success. However, I could not copy and paste directly from the code blocks above. I had to copy and paste from the value for the variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` directly from my Help window (starting from a non-org-mode buffer). My particular values included a long series of dashes, but that is likely due to my local squirrelly font setup.